# How to store dynamically populated select field value in database

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

Here is my form field.

```
  <div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label for="username" class="control-label">Designation:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <select name="designation" class="form-control">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
            <?php
            $sql = mysqli_query($db->link_id, "SELECT designation FROM tbl_designation");
            while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option value=\"designation\">" . $row['designation'] . "</option>";
            }

            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here I am posting the form values,

```
$designation  = $_POST['designation'];
```

On posting, $designation has value as "designation" but not the selected value.

Can anyone please help and let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: because you have `value=\"designation\"` instead of `value=\"$row['designation']\"`

Comment: Many thanks.. It worked mate .:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are giving a static value **'designation'** to your options that's why you are getting

> $designation has value as "designation" but not the selected value.

So just replace this

```
echo "<option value=\"designation\">" . $row['designation'] . "</option>";
```

with

```
echo "<option value=" . $row['designation'] . ">" . $row['designation'] . "</option>";
```

I thing it will work for you.

Comment: Now i have same issue with another select box which is not showing any value as well as field name in the array when var_dump() is used on POST. This also contains the same table value as designation. Can be fixed? I have changed into the same as u recommended for designation but no success on that

Comment: <select name="reporting_head" class="form-control" >
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
            <?php
           $sql = mysqli_query($db->link_id, "SELECT designation FROM tbl_designation");
                  while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){   
          echo "<option value=" . $row['designation'] . ">" . $row['designation'] . "</option>";
}
?>
        </select>

Answer (score 4):

you are giving option value as `designation` for each option, so whatever option you select always its value will be `designation` only change this line in your code as

```
echo "<option value='".$row['designation']."'>" . $row['designation'] . "</option>";
```

Comment: Now i have same issue with another select box which is not showing any value as well as field name in the array when var_dump() is used on POST. This also contains the same table value as designation. Can be fixed? I have changed into the same as u recommended for designation but no success on that

Comment: <select name="reporting_head" class="form-control" > <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option> <?php $sql = mysqli_query($db->link_id, "SELECT designation FROM tbl_designation"); while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){ echo "<option value=" . $row['designation'] . ">" . $row['designation'] . "</option>"; } ?> </select> –